# I already create a table at the same access file but when I save information to that database it pop out NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, copy, ms-access-2010, nullreferenceexception, oledbcommand

I'm doing a todo list vb.net, I have 2 button name Complete and Execute, when the user press Complete, the interface will let user to choose which task has been executed, and the task is from table name `todolist` and if the user press Execute on this task then it will do a copy to table name `complete`. But every time I run the program it appear NullreferenceException, but I already create the table.

I wonder is there my logic thinking or the system? Can anyone tell me where is my mistake?

Here is my Execute button

```
Private Sub btnexecute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnexecute.Click
    If inc <> -1 Then
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daa)
        cb.QuotePrefix = "["
        cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
        con.Open()
        dsNewRow = dss.Tables("complete").NewRow() `exception occur`

    dsNewRow.Item("Task") = txtitem.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("description") = txtdescript.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("Date of create") = dtptoday.Text
    dsNewRow.Item("Date of execute") = dtpcomplete.Text

    dss.Tables("complete").Rows.Add(dsNewRow) 
    MaxRows = MaxRows + 1

    da.Update(dss, "complete")
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Task has been executed, will be remove here and put in!")

`enable and disable button
    btncomplete.Enabled = True
    btnSave.Enabled = False
    btnadd.Enabled = True
    btnUpdate.Enabled = True
    btnremove.Enabled = True

    inc = 0

`navigate records
    NavigateRecords()

End If
End Sub
```

Here is my complete button

```
  Private Sub btncomplete_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncomplete.Click

    btnSave.Enabled = False
    btnadd.Enabled = False
    btnUpdate.Enabled = False
    btnremove.Enabled = False
    btnexecute.Enabled = True

`call back the record from todolist table
    NavigateRecords()

End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly does the Exception occur?

Comment: `dsNewRow = dss.Tables("complete").NewRow()` @MrPaulch

Comment: Use `Dim dsNewRow As New DataRow` instead `Dim dsNewRow As DataRow`

Comment: `Error 1  System.Data.DataRow.Protected Friend Sub New(builder As System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected Friend'. ` Error :\ @equisde

Comment: Well the `Dim dsNewRow As New DataRow` idea was bs. Try to check whether `dss.Tables("complete")` is null. (By stepping through)

Comment: [what is a nullreferenceexception and how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)